# Curl Request with multiple lines

Tags: curl

I used Chrome Dev Tools to look at a curl request. When I select 'Copy as cURL', it gave me the following output.

[image]

How would I make this request be a single line without messing the code up? Would replacing all instances of `\r\n` with a blank character do the trick?

Comment: You don't need to. Use  `-F` for each multipart body part, e.g. `-F "appid=123445566" -F "actions=generate"`. This will set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` implicitly. I'm curious though if multipart is really what you want. By looking at the data, seems like maybe it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Who knows

Comment: If `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is what you really need, then you can do `-d "appid=12334343&actions=generate&submitted=1"`

Comment: @peeskillet: If you submit your comment as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. Use `-F` for each multipart body part, e.g.

```
-F "appid=123445566" -F "actions=generate"
```

This will set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` implicitly.

I'm curious though if multipart is really what you want. By looking at the data, seems like maybe it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I'm not sure. If `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is what you really need, then you can do

```
-d "appid=12334343&actions=generate&submitted=1"
```